# Busca MongoDB Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho estes dois documentos no mongo:

```
/* 0 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54f395ef7a5a5ea37af77398"),

"HISTORICO" : [],
"MOTIVO" : "",
"RP_CANCELAMENTO" : "",
"DATA_CANCELAMENTO" : null,
"RP_FINALIZACAO" : "",
"DATA_FINALIZACAO" : null,
"STATUS_CHAMADO" : "aberto",
"SOLICITACAO" : "teste.",
"DATA_CHAMADO" : ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"RP_CHAMADO" : "cristineia evangelista",
"EMAIL_SOLICITANTE" : "",
"TEL_COMERCIAL_SOLICITANTE" : "",
"TEL_RESIDENCIAL_SOLICITANTE" : "(39)00390300_",
"SOLICITANTE" : "Luciana",
"TEL_COMERCIAL_PROPRIETARIO" : "null",
"DDD_PROPRIETARIO" : "38",
"PRIORIDADE" : "media",
"BAIRRO" : "CENTRO",
"CODIGO_IMOVEL" : "03806/2",
"CODIGO_CONTRATO" : "16161",
"__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54f395d47a5a5ea37af77397"),
"RP_ABERTURA" : "guilherme ferreira",
"HISTORICO" : [ 
    [ 
        {
            "DATA_HISTORICO" : "2015-03-01",
            "DADOS_HISTORICO" : "opa",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54f396de7a5a5ea37af77399")
        }
    ], 
    [ 
        {
            "DATA_HISTORICO" : "2015-03-01",
            "DADOS_HISTORICO" : "opa",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54f397437a5a5ea37af7739a")
        }
    ], 
    [ 
        {
            "DATA_HISTORICO" : "2015-03-01",
            "DADOS_HISTORICO" : "teste",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54f39759c8d6e8e17ca7822c")
        }
    ], 
    [ 
        {
            "DATA_HISTORICO" : "2015-03-01",
            "DADOS_HISTORICO" : "teste",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54f397d1c8d6e8e17ca7822d")
        }
    ]
],
"MOTIVO" : "",
"RP_CANCELAMENTO" : "",
"DATA_CANCELAMENTO" : null,
"RP_FINALIZACAO" : "",
"DATA_FINALIZACAO" : null,
"STATUS_CHAMADO" : "aberto",
"SOLICITACAO" : "teste de chaad.",
"DATA_CHAMADO" : ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"RP_CHAMADO" : "erika ramires",
"EMAIL_SOLICITANTE" : "",
"SOLICITANTE" : "Luciana",
"DDD_PROPRIETARIO" : "38",
"NOME_PROPRIETARIO" : "PAULINA FRANCELINA DOS SANTOS",
"PRIORIDADE" : "media",
"BAIRRO" : "VL GUILHERMINA",
"ENDERECO" : "R LEOBINO CAMARA 55",
"CODIGO_IMOVEL" : "5971",
"CODIGO_CONTRATO" : "14298",
"__v" : 0
}
```

Como faço para buscar um histórico especifico ?

Comment: resposta com elemMatch resolveu?

Answer (score 3):

Olá, para buscar um histórico específico, utilize o operador $elemMatch:

```
db.teste.find({HISTORICO: {$elemMatch: {DADOS_HISTORICO:"teste"}}})
```

[Documentação do mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

[Pergunta semelhante em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198429/mongodb-how-to-find-out-if-an-array-field-contains-an-element)

Comment: elemMatch resolveu?

Answer (score 2):

Você usa a função/query `db.<nomeDB>.find()` para fazer essa consulta.

Supondo que o nome da BD seja "test", o comando `db.test.find()` retornaria todos os registros.

Mas você quer filtrar os resultados, certo?

Então o comando seria `db.test.find({atributo: 'valor'})`. E sim, o valor DEVE estar entre `'` (apóstrofe).

**Exemplo**: Você quer todos os documentos abertos? Então a consulta `db.test.find({STATUS_CHAMADO:'aberto'})` seria a consulta que você queria.

Se você quer apenas um documento, basta trocar o comando por `findOne`.

**Exemplo**: A consulta `db.test.findOne({STATUS_CHAMADO:'aberto'})` retornaria apenas um documento aberto.

[Fonte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Guilherme, não ficou muito claro o que você precisa, mas vou te enviar duas formas, uma delas deve lhe atender.

Para esse tipo de questão, prefiro utilizar o aggregate, estou fazendo a busca com base no ID do histórico que deseja. Na primeira consulta, estou retornando todas as informações de determinado histórico:

```
db.teste.aggregate(
[
    { $unwind: "$HISTORICO" },
    { $match: { 'HISTORICO._id': ObjectId('54f39759c8d6e8e17ca7822c') } }
])
```

Nessa segunda consulta, retorno apenas as informações do Historico buscando pelo seu ID:

```
db.teste.aggregate(
[
    { $unwind: "$HISTORICO" },
    { $match: { 'HISTORICO._id': ObjectId('54f39759c8d6e8e17ca7822c') } },
    { $project: { 'HISTORICO': 1, '_id': 0 } }
])
```

Espero ter ajudado.